# How to use localDb without lost Data by using EF in c#

Tags: c#, database, windows, entity-framework

I'm developing a Windows Forms application that I need to storage some data as a database in user's system, so that I would be able to access my database through Entity Framework. I mean I need to copy a database (tables should be created already) from the resources directory to specific directory. Then use it with Entity Framework. To be honest I have no idea. That's my problem!

Comment: You mean copy file database from dir1 to dir2 ? by using EF ?

Comment: Not really; I need to copy a mdf database from software resources folder to one specific directory then use it as data source from Entity Framework, because when I use the database located in resources folder, changes would not been saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make sample fixed problem for all project when create **winforms & localdb**

You can create 2 **ConnectionString** in App.config file

### App.config

```
<add name="DevConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> <!--  *1* Use when publish project--> 

<!--<add name="AppConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='E:\My Projects\MyDatabase.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
<!--*2* Use for development-->
```