# SQL Server stored procedure access to retrieve data and display to users

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Can anyone help me with this problem? I have a Winforms app using a SQL Server connection string (with Windows authentication) to retrieve all the data.

When I published the program as an app and let anyone in the team to use, my db owner has to assign the role as db owner in the system so other members can use it. Otherwise it just pops the error all the time.

For the integrity purposes, we don't want anyone in the team to be a db owner, is any way that I can implement my program without assigning role for other members as db owner. I tried to use standard way but I don't have username and password.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DBAB" 
             connectionString="Server=******;Database=****;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    
    <startup> C:\2020\IRP\App.config
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Trusted connection - you have this application running under some identity that has permissions? Or are you passing through user auth? Whichever the case, for the identity running the query, you make a role, like MyAppUser, and assign perms to that role. Well, your DB person does, if you don't. Our winforms app has its own identity that it uses to connect with so we don't have to mess with individual users.

Comment: The problem is in the stored procedure definition. As @Nikki9696 says, create a role, and assign all of the windows users to that role. Then, as the last line of the stored procedure definition, grant execute permission to the role. `GRANT EXECUTE ON your_sp_name TO MyAppUser;`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983815/12777835